# Please let me know the Areas where we can apply the concept "Mixin" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mixins

Recently I came across a strange word "Mixin". Got to know that it is something related to "has-a-relationship" in OOPS. A class can be utilized without inheriting it but by having its object in another class. This is very clear. Coming to Magento 2, I have seen many articles which are relating this term to javascript, CSS Less etc.

I am curious to know the application of "mixins" in Magento 2. I can understand that as it is related to OOPs it can apply everywhere but what is the situation or a real time scenario where this will be more helpful and meaningful?

Comment: Hi @Teja  may I know please why the last line was removed?

Comment: Hello Kalyan, The description which you have explained above is enough. So i removed the thing

Answer (score 1):

In terms of javascript, the mixin approach allows to modify (extend/overwrite) result that a JavaScript component returns before it is used anywhere.

In my case, I needed to add a function called `getBgColor` in order to change the backgound and the font color of the grid element.

see my exemple:

```
define([
'Magento_Ui/js/grid/listing',
'prototype'], function (listing, prototype) {
'use strict';

var mixin = {

    defaults: {
        template: 'MyModule_ColorOrders/grid/listing'
    },

    /**
     * Handler of the colors
     */
    getBgColor: function (data) {

        if (typeof data.admin_color_order != 'undefined' || data.admin_color_order != null) {

            return {
                "backgroundColor": '#' + data.admin_color_order,
                "color": '#' + data.admin_color_order_text,
            };
        }
    },

};

return listing.extend(mixin); });
```

You can see more examples at [Magento DevDocs  Js-Mixin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html)

Comment: Feel free to set this answer as correct :P

Comment: Sure :) let me try please

Comment: Just to let you know, this code is just a part of an entire `Color Orders` extension. This snippet itself has no effective result at all.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Will use yours as a base and build my example.

Answer (score 0):

magento 2 doing for checkout agreement

check below file for same:-
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/CheckoutAgreements/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js